# NoClassDefFoundError exception after having created jar file

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have created a jar file including inside it some packages and a pair of file. This class file uses another package that I hadn't include in the jar file - I think that's the reason I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JigMonitorGUI (wrong name: org/w3c/jigmonitor/JigMonitorGUI)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

EDIT

the whole stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JigMonitorGUI (wrong name:  org/w3c/jigmonitor/JigMonitorGUI)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you haven't quite created your JAR file correctly.  Your class file has a package, but it seems you're attempting to run the class not within a directory structure matching the package of the class.

Let's provide a demonstration of how you can reproduce this error message. Suppose we have the following class:

```
package abc.def.ghi;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Note that this class is in the package `abc.def.ghi`. Suppose we save this as `Hello.java` in a directory `C:\Users\Luke\Java` and then compile it from this directory:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Java>javac Hello.java
```

We then create a JAR file using the `Hello.class` file:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Java>jar cf test.jar Hello.class
```

Finally, we then try to run this class from within the JAR:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Java>java -cp test.jar Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: abc/def/ghi/Hello)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        ...
```

This is the error you're getting, but with a different class name.

The problem is that the class `Hello` wasn't compiled within a directory structure matching its package.  The JVM found the class in the root of the JAR so it expected the fully-qualified name of the class inside the class file to be `Hello`.  However, the fully-qualified name in the class file was `abc.def.ghi.Hello`, which wasn't what the JVM was expecting, so it threw an error.

If we instead have `Hello.java` within subdirectories `abc\def\ghi`, matching its package `abc.def.ghi`, things work a little better:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Java>javac abc\def\ghi\Hello.java

C:\Users\Luke\Java>jar cf test.jar abc\def\ghi\Hello.class

C:\Users\Luke\Java>java -cp test.jar abc.def.ghi.Hello
Hello
```

**EDIT**: it's possible to reproduce the same errors by running the class directly, without creating a JAR.  The key point is still that you're attempting to run the class from outside of a directory structure matching its hierarchy.

At this point I have `Hello.class` in `C:\Users\Luke\Java` and `C:\Users\Luke\Java\abc\def\ghi`:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Java>java Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: abc/def/ghi/Hello)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        ...

C:\Users\Luke\Java>java abc.def.ghi.Hello
Hello
```

Comment: well I'll explain my situation I have a folder with 3 subfolders and one class file that it is the main.what I should do to create correctly the jar file?

Comment: @Mazzy: It's possible to reproduce the error without using a JAR file, and if the error is with the file not in the JAR, then the JAR may well have been created OK.  (Apologies for missing this detail.)  Exactly how are you running your class?  Is `JigMonitorGUI` one of the classes in the JAR or is it the main class?

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the missing .class file when you run your application.

```
java -jar -cp <path_to_missing_jars_here> yourJarName.jar
```

Comment: @Mazzy Try passing (besides the usual jars) the current directory to the classpath as well. Like this: `java -jar -classpath .;jar1.jar;jar2.jar application.jar`.

Comment: could you share the whole stacktrace with us?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invoking with `java -cp whatever -jar app.jar` you should edit the jar's manifest file. Something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: abc.def.Whatever
Class-Path: jar1.jar jar2.jar jar3.jar
```

(And don't forget the empty line at the end of the manifest...)

Answer (score 0):

The missing classes need to be on the classpath. How to do this will depend on how you want to deploy/run your application.

Comment: The classes aren't missing.  The JVM found the class file, but the class file had the wrong fully-qualified class name.